# Use Angular-translate in $stateProvider param

Tags: angularjs

Here is my route config file

```
$stateProvider.state('process', {
      url: '/process',
      params: {
        title: 'Process Name'
      },
      views: {
        'processDemo': {
          component: 'process'
        }
      },
      resolve: {
        translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
          $translatePartialLoader.addPart('demo');
          return $translate.refresh();
        }]
      }
    });
```

Here is my demo.json file

```
{
 "name": "Process"
}
```

I want to use demo.json name in my config file. Anybody can help for this?